PyQT6 не получается получить ширину QGridLayout из его обёртки
Нужно была обёртка QGridLayout, но при попытке получить ширину, я получал пустые значения.
class WorkAreaGrid(QGridLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        #self.setVerticalSpacing(0)
        #self.setSpacing(0)
        #self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)
    
    def addWidgetDefault(self, w):

        # ошибка!!!
        # ---------------------------------------------------------------

        width = self.geometry().width()  # ширина макета, ошибочное значение 0, всегда!!
        print(super().geometry())  # пустой QRect всегда(вывод 'PyQt6.QtCore.QRect()')


        # ----------------------------------------------------------------
        width_w = w.width()  # с размерами виджета всё ок
        print(width, width_w) # вывод: '0 60'
        n = (width // width_w) + 1
        #print(n)
        x = len(self) % n
        y = len(self) // n
        #print(x, y)
        super().addWidget(w, x, y)

В выделенной зоне width всегда получает 0, а QRect всегда пустой.
Не могли бы сказать, как мне получить корректные значения ширины? Заранее спасибо!

Даже из другого класса не могу получить корректные значения.

Руслан, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать. Какие действия вы собираетесь выполнять и какой результат вы желаете получить? Ваш комментарий, что пустой QRect всегда - не понятен, опубликуйте в теле вопроса принты, которые вы получаете.

Добавил значение вывода. Извините если побеспокоил, но скорее всего закрою вопрос, ибо придётся менять подход к задаче.

Извините, что забрал ваше время.

Руслан, если вам нужна помощь - предоставьте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему и хорошо расскажите что вы хотите сделать. В примере, который я создаю для своего теста, никаких пустых   значений не получается. Я не понимаю что вы хотите сделать, а в моем примере после вызова метода addWidgetDefault(self, w), виджет  w куда-то перемещается.

Не могли вы бы подсказать как расположить один виджет над другим, не прибегая к Layout?

Руслан, я бы вам что-нибудь посоветовал, но я не понимаю того, что вы хотите сделать. Предоставьте свой код или минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему и хорошо расскажите что вы хотите сделать. Может вы хотите сделать резиновую ленту?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1593719/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bc-pyqt6
